# What is difference between pnpm create, pnpx, dlx?

Tags: npm, npx, pnpm

The `pnpm` package manager offers three commands that are alternatives for `npm`'s `npx` command. These are `pnpm create`, `pnpx` and `pnpm dlx`. All three seem to do the same thing. But what are the differences between them? Which one should be preferred for which tasks? Or is there a universal best?

Comment: See also [Can I use npx with pnpm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75413361/can-i-use-npx-with-pnpm)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As of v7, [`pnpm dlx`](https://pnpm.io/cli/dlx) is the same as `pnpx`. It downloads a package and executes it.

[`pnpm create`](https://pnpm.io/cli/create) is a shorthand for `pnpm dlx`, when you need to create an app. So, for instance, `pnpm create react-app my-app` will download the `create-react-app` package and run it to bootstrap a react app. It is the same as running `pnpm dlx create-react-app my-app`.

There is also [`pnpm exec`](https://pnpm.io/cli/exec), which doesn't download a package just runs a package that is already in `node_modules/.bin`

Comment: So technically they are just one and the same command with different syntax? And the preferred syntax is the one I personally like the most?

Comment: `pnpm dlx` and `pnpx` are the same. `pnpm create` does some additional stuff as I mentioned. It changes the package name that should be downloaded.

Comment: Note that pnpx is [deprecated](https://pnpm.io/6.x/pnpx-cli). Use pnpm dlx instead

Comment: but pnpm dlx seems to have an issue with parameters? I was trying to install prisma using pnpx prisma init -datasource=provider sqlite and got the "deprecated" with pnpm exec or pnpm dlx. Of course exec wont work but pnpm dlx prisma init -datasource=provider sqlite wouldnt work either as it cant use a parameter?? I ran without parameter and adjusted files manually. I then ran into another issue where I want "prisma": { "seed": "pnpm dlx vite-node prisma/seed.ts" in package.json. It appears to run but I get no data. Is there a solution for passing parameters?

Comment: @ZoltanKochan how is it different from npx?

Comment: npx works like both `pnpm dlx` and `pnpm exec`. If it find a locally installed command, then it executes it, if it does find it, then it downloads and executes it.

Comment: but I dont understand what's the 'p' infront of pnpm and pnpx means.  What's the difference between p infront and without ?  Thanks.

Comment: [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) is an alternative package manager. npm and pnpm are two different package managers. p means "performant" - performant npm.

Comment: pnpm create worked best for me.  I used it as a replacement for npx