# Can I use npx with pnpm?

Tags: npm, npx, pnpm

Can I use `npx` together with a `pnpm` install?

It doesn't seem to work and `pnpx` fetches remote dependencies, it seems more like `npm create`.

Is there a way to use `npx` with `pnpm` to execute local binaries or is there a different `pnpm` equivalent?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

The are are two key uses of `npx`.

**Running executables inside your downloaded dependencies**

For example `npx jest`.

The pnpm equivalent is `pnpm exec jest`.

**Running executable commands in packages you want to download transiently**

For example `npx create-react-app my-app`.

The pnpm equivalent of this is `pnpm dlx create-react-app my-app`.

Note: There used to be a `pnpx` command, but it has been [deprecated](https://web.archive.org/web/20230202163724/https://pnpm.io/6.x/pnpx-cli).

Comment: FYI you can use `pnpm jest` if you like typing less

Answer (score 17):

Based on [PNPM Feature Comparison](https://pnpm.io/feature-comparison) the alternative to **NPX** in **PNPM** should `pnpm dlx`

Comment: Not if you're running a dependency. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Comment from the [addition of dlx](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/pull/3652):

> npx is also kind of deprecated and replaced by `npm exec`.

Which probably refers to npx being [deprecated as standalone package](https://github.com/npm/npx/commit/34660901133c8e890c1076d11b744ea20d9511c2#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5R1) and [inclusion into npm itself by use of `npm exec`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx#compatibility-with-older-npx-versions) . The [main difference](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npx#npx-vs-npm-exec) is now that

**`npm exec` supports `--` to end argument parsing** for itself and count following args to the package to be run.

Whereas **npx** requires all **args to itself** to be given **before the package** to be run and couts all following arguments to the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer yes.
`npx create-next-app@latest --use-pnpm`